# is there a way to load a json file containing the mapping of an index with the elasticsearch java api?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, mapping

My mapping is too long and to optimize my code i would like to put the json format of the mapping in a json file and load it with elasticsearch java api. But i didn't find a way to do that. I want to use this mapping just for one index not for all.

Comment: Does it has to be the elasticsearch **java** api or would the Elasticsearch REST API called with curl be also a solution?

Comment: With the Java API you can easily read the content of the file using Java IO/NIO and then send that content.

Comment: Thanks for your replies, i have found a solution with @Val solution. I read my file and stored the content in a string variable which i pass to the mapping request.

Comment: You should maybe add an answer and show what you did, as other people might find this helpful ;-)

Comment: @Val, I am using this very heavily in my project and provided the answer containing the code :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint is already given by @Val, But as I use it my code and had code for this handy, so thought of posting it here :

Utility code to read JSON mapping from a file in a String format:

```
/**
 * Get String from file Which contains Index mapping in JSON format.
 *
 * @param fileName file which needs to be read into JSON.
 * @return
 */
public String getStringFromFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
    ClassLoader classLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
    InputStream in = classLoader.getResourceAsStream(fileName);
    ByteArrayOutputStream result = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        result.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    return result.toString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
}
```

Using above code, you can easily create an index, using the `CreateIndexRequest` API of java high-level elasticsearch rest client:

```
void createIndex(RestHighLevelClient client) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
            if (!isIndexExist(client, indexName)) {
                String indexString = getStringFromFile("your file name");
                CreateIndexRequest request = new CreateIndexRequest(indexName);
                request.source(indexString, XContentType.JSON);
                client.indices().create(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
            }
    }
```

Let me know if you face any issue and have doubt in any loc.

Answer (score 1):

Late post.

This can be achieved in a single line using `apache commons-io`.

Add the dependency :

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </dependency>
```

And then in the code simply do :

```
String jsonFileinString = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("Your File"), "UTF-8")
```